# Laravel - One to Many relationship is not working one way

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue in Laravel where in a One to Many relationship, it returns null if using it from one side (the side that "hasMany"), but the other way around (the side that "belongsTo") returns the containing object. In my case, a category can have many threads and all threads belong to one category.

Below is the relevant code:

Category:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function threads() {
        $this->hasMany('App\Thread', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Thread:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Where I try to get it:

```
Thread::with('category')->get();
$latestThread = dd(Category::find(1)->threads());
```

The table structure for each is below:
Category:

```
id, name, description
```

Thread:

```
id, name, user_id, category_id
```

(The dd outputs null in case you were wondering). If you need anything else, please ask!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed the **return** keyword in your threads function

```
public function threads() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Thread', 'category_id');
}
```

Comment: I figured it would be something silly like this,  thank you!